# Im skinny but not shredded.Should i do cardio and weightlifting both or will the one influence the other?

Tags: weightlifting, cardio

![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OT

Comment: The image can't be opened as it stands. It would be nice if you would proof-read your post before you submit it. Also, we can't tell you what you "should" do without knowing what it is you want to accomplish. And preferably in more detail than what is in the title.

Comment: Also "shredded" is generally not sustainable long term. Stage look is generally only for a few hours.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given a lot of information, as @Alec stated in the comment, if you provide more info we'll  be able to give a more detailed answer.

Based on the info you gave, I'd say don't do any cardio right from the start. I'm assuming you want to gain some muscle size while maintaining a relatively low bodyfat percentage since you used the word shredded.

What I advice you to do is start doing strenght training, 3 to 5 days a week. To get shredded I'd mix bodybuilding style workouts with heavy compound lifts. You'll also need to eat loads and get enough rest. How much food you need is something you're going to need to figure out yourself that's impossible for me to say.

You can do cardio if you enjoy it, but just know it can be detrimental to your muscle gains, or you'll need to eat even more calories to make up for the calories you lose during cardio. Once you start gaining more fat than you want, you can start adding some cardio to your workout routine.